# Circular segmented slider control in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider, controls

Is there any JavaScript (even better if it's based on jQuery) slider that is circular in shape and that also allogs to draw segments on the circle. Here's a drawing of a sample of what I'd like to achieve:

[image: circular slider with slices]

As you can see, the yellow slices are those that have been selected, while all the rest is just a background image (this is done on an iOS device with a custom control).
It would be nice to find something similar for HTML pages if there's any around.
Thanks!

Comment: This site has malware according to Chrome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using a custom solution based on [oCanvas](http://ocanvas.org/).

Answer (score 1):

This might be useful. It's very good.

[jquery-knob](http://anthonyterrien.com/knob/)

Comment: This is nice but it doesn't support multiple arc on the same circular corona.